# Appengine Datastore Read Operations limit exceeded

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, blobstore

I keep reaching the limit of Read Operations exceeded which is 50k for less than two hours without much activity. In the datastore I have about 200 records of a class that contains 8 variables in the short type in Java. The user can add new instances in this class in the datastore.

Each time the user reaches the website I have to show the results so I can show to  max 50 000/ 200 = 250 users (usually even much less).

Is there any other way I can store the results persistently? Maybe I can put the 200 records as one and parse them manually in the code.

I read about blobstore but I understand it's more about uploading files rather than database and querying. Should I use it. I want to keep the application in the free tier.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to show the same records to all users, keep them in Memcache - or even in your instance memory.

Comment: The user inserts the data so it's constantly updating. It's about evaluating a class for certain criteria from 2 to 6 and when a new evaluation is marked I need to update the averages and etc.

Comment: You asked about read operations - you can dramatically reduce them by using Memcache. All updates, inserts, etc. can be reflected in Memcache as well.

Comment: Alternatively, your data set is so small that it will fit into a single datastore entity (up to 1MB) - or a few entities if necessary. Just serialize your data and store it as a long String.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am implementing exactly this at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Check out **[Objectify](https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki)** if you're using Java.  It has first and second level cache (second level uses Memecache as Andrei recommended).  Objectify will help you avoid repeated trips to the datastore--it all happens out of the box with no re-coding on your part.  Just read about the `@Cache` annotation for entity objects as well as the `Objectify.cache(true)` method.